# Does a Kivy 1.9.x (pre)release exists for Windows?

Tags: python, build, kivy, bin

Hej,

For Linux useing git and building your own kivy version is an easy way to use the 1.9.x version.

Doing it on windows seems mutch more dificult, because you have to setup your enviroment in a proper way.

Christoph Golke runs a nice website containing builds of many python libs([www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs)). He uses PyPi and of course there are only the main releases(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kivy).

So is there an other website etc. where a Windows user can get prebuild a kivy 1.9.x for windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not provide any prerelease Windows packages. It's fairly easy to update the 1.8.0 package to use the newest Kivy - however, while this will get you the updated Kivy code, it will not have all the features of 1.9.0. We have switched to using SDL2 instead of Pygame by default, and you need the SDL2 libs/headers to compile it.

However, we are also very close to releasing 1.9.0, so we should have a new Windows package soon with the latest code and SDL2 support.

But if you really want the newest code now, you can update it. Just remember that it won't have SDL2 support.

1. Go to the portable package directory
2. Rename the `kivy` folder to `kivy.stable`
3. Put the development source in a new `kivy` folder

   - If you have git, you can simply run `git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git`
   - Otherwise, [download the source zip](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip), extract, and rename the resulting folder from `kivy-<some hash>` to `kivy`
4. Open a shell/cmd window with `kivy.bat`
5. Update Cython by typing `python -m pip install --upgrade Cython==0.21.2`
6. cd to the `kivy` folder and type `make force`

And you're done!

Comment: We just tagged version 1.9.0 today! Should have a new Windows package available for download by this weekend or sooner.